# Basic evaluation of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you evaluate the following limit as n goes to infinity?

$$\lim \frac {1}{(1+\frac {1}{n})^n}$$

I would of thought that this would evaluated to be,

$$\lim \frac {1}{(1)^n} = 0 $$

However the correct answer is $$\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not** answer like that because you are not allowed to seperate the limit in those two limits.

**Hint:**
Use (the definition)
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \mathrm e.$$

Comment: so that definition should just be memorized and then it would be simply $\frac {1}{e}$

Comment: Yes, if this is your definition of $\mathrm e$.

Comment: Well, it's *one* possible definition of $\mathrm e$. Another possible definition is $$\mathrm e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}.$$ When using this definition for $\mathrm e$, you certainly do have to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n = \mathrm e$.

Comment: @celtschk And yet another definition is the inverse function of $\int_1^x \frac1t \,dt$.  But the OP has not provided any information to suggest a starting definition.